# Special Passport Authentication for Specific Route

Tags: node.js, rest, express, passport.js, restful-authentication

I'm developing a RESTful API with Express.js and I'm using Passport.js for authentication purposes.
Here is an example of how I'm using passport with routes:

```
const beerRoutes = require('./beerRoutes')     // an instance of express router
let authenticateRoute = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })

router.use('/beer', authenticateRoute, beerRoutes)
```

Inside beerRoutes.js :

```
const router = require('express').Router()

router.post('/', (req, res) => {})
router.get('/', (req, res) => {})
router.patch('/', (req, res) => {})
router.delete('/', (req, res) => {})
```

The problem is, I want unauthenticated clients to be able to create new users (i.e. `POST /beer/`).
But I also want to give additional permissions to authenticated clients when they send a request to the same endpoint.

How can I achieve this without letting unauthenticated clients to access other routes inside `beerRoutes` (e.g. `PATCH /beer/`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be addressed with a custom middleware which calls the *Passport.js* middleware.

```
const authenticationWhiteList = [
  'POST /beer'
]


function Authenticate (request, response, next) {
  let route = `${request.method} ${request.baseUrl}`

  if (_.indexOf(authenticationWhiteList, route) !== -1) {
    next()
  } else {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })(request, response, next)
  }
}
```

Then change the authentication code to this one:

```
const beerRoutes = require('./beerRoutes')     // an instance of express router

// let authenticateRoute = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })
let authenticateRoute = Authenticate


router.use('/beer', authenticateRoute, beerRoutes)
```